# How do I create custom Edit Views MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing an application with MVC4 and VBNet using Entity Framework. I have two models, Printer.vb and Request.vb

They are as shown below,

Request.vb

```
    Public Class Request
        Public Property ID() As Integer
        Public Property User() As String
        Public Property Printer() As Printer
        Public Property Approval() As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class RequestDBContext
        Inherits DbContext
        Public Property Requests() As DbSet(Of Request)
    End Class
```

Printer.vb

```
    Public Class Printer
        Public Property ID() As Integer
        Public Property Name() As String
    End Class

    Public Class PrinterDBContext
        Inherits DbContext
        Public Property Printers() As DbSet(Of Printer)
    End Class
```

I'm having trouble creating Requests that reference a Printer model that exists in the database.

My Request view looks like this,

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.User)
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Approval)
        @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Printer)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.User)
    </div>
```

But the `Model.EditorFor(model.Printer) doesn't create anything.

How do I add a field to the request view that will find a Printer and reference it in that request?

Comment: you can add an editor template for Printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't just use `@Html.EditorFor()` on a type that the MVC framework knows nothing about.

The Framework already knows how to handle `@Html.EditorFor()` for common basic types like String, and int.

What you need to do is follow a tutorial like this [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) , or you can just Google "Custom Editor Templates Asp.net MVC"

basically you are going to create a file in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Printer.vbhtml and tell MVC framework what to display.

in your Printer.vbhtml it will look something like

```
   @model Printer

   @Html.Textbox("", Model.ID.GetValueOrDefault())
   @Html.Textbox("", Model.Name.GetValueOrDefault())
```